# How to change first three letters of a word

Tags: css, css-selectors

I wanted to create a **wordpress** website and in its live ***CSS*** edit part I selected the website name "**Standard**" and then I tried to change the first letters using `:nth-child` and `:nth-letter` pseudo classes. But I can't. Can I edit the site name with ***CSS styles***. The way I chose to select the word was using these classes: **header .logo .site-title** and I put the pseudo-classes like this:

```
header .logo .site-title:nth-child(1):nth-letter(-n+2) {
    color: pink;
}
```

And so the way I tried has'nt worked. Can you help me to solve the problem and people who are searching about this?

Comment: is the text in his own line or is it in the middle of some other text?

Comment: This is not possible with CSS as you cannot select `nth-letter`s of text.

Answer (score -1):

```
.site-title {
color: pink;
}
```

Try to use this CSS

```
.site-title:after {
color: black;
color: blue;
content: attr(data-descr);
left: 0;
position: absolute;
}
```

And HTML

```
<div class="site-title" data-descr="S T">SITE TITLE</div>
```

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: It worked for me in Wordpress! thank you so much.